# CLSQL timestamp Column Type

Tags: mysql, common-lisp, sbcl, clsql

I'm using CLSQL with MySQL. What combination of keywords do I have to pass to `create-table` in order to give it a column with the timestamp column type?

```
(create-table [foo] `(([bar] timestamp)))
```

is unrecognized (it just creates a varchar 255 column, which is the default if you don't specify a column type). According to [this reference page](http://clsql.b9.com/manual/def-view-class.html), `wall-time` should create a timestamp column, but just creates a `datetime` (which is not the same thing as a MySQL `timestamp`).

Also, is there a better CLSQL column type reference than the one I linked above?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use datetime? The only difference which I found is the range.
Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

```
The DATETIME type is used when you need values that contain both date and time information. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

The TIMESTAMP data type has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.
```

If you look at the sources of clsql, for example [here](http://git.b9.com/?p=clsql.git;a=blob;f=db-mysql/mysql-objects.lisp;h=015edbb6501791e3a45f82889f10ffc6f7ebfe9c;hb=HEAD), you will see

```
  (defmethod database-get-type-specifier ((type (eql 'wall-time)) args database
                                           (db-type (eql :mysql)))
    (declare (ignore args database))
     "DATETIME")
```

It means that everything is fine  with your code. What quote do you use a back-quote ` or simple quote \' ?

Comment: A MySQL `TIMESTAMP` can be set to automatically update each time its record is `UPDATE`d. A `DATETIME` has to be set explicitly.